# Saving user-uploaded images in asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, image, aurelia

I'm trying to post an uploaded image from the front-end using aurelia to a asp.net mvc. Is there someway I can save the image received in as png format in a folder on the server?

Javascript method from where I'm posting the image data(files is the uploaded image and id is the unique image ID that I need to use for the file name)

```
saveImage(files,id) {
        var form = new FormData()
        form.append('file', files)
        form.append('ID', id)

        this.http.fetch('/api/Employees', {
            method: 'post',
            body: form
        })

        return true;
    }
```

ImagesController(Asp.net MVC)

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace SPAproject.Controllers
{
    public class ImagesController : Controller
    {
        [HttpPost, Route("api/[controller]")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> SaveImage()
        {
            try
            {
                var form = await Request.ReadFormAsync();
                var file = form.Files.First();

                var id = form.ElementAt(1);
                var path = "/images/" + id + ".png";
                Stream stream = file.OpenReadStream();

                return Ok(true);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                var originalMessage = ex.Message;

                while (ex.InnerException != null)
                    ex = ex.InnerException;
                return BadRequest($"{originalMessage} | {ex.Message}");
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
string fileName = string.Format("{0}{1}", id, ".png");
var serverPath = Server.MapPath("~/images");
var path = Path.Combine(serverPath, fileName);

using (Stream inputStream = file.OpenReadStream())
using (var outputStream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create))
{
    // dump a stream to a file
    inputStream.CopyTo(outputStream);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume you use ASP.NET Core, not ASP.NET(using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;)

You can use new class in asp.net core, IFormFile. It simplifies the stream operations.

```
[HttpPost("UploadFiles")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Post(List<IFormFile> files)
{
    long size = files.Sum(f => f.Length);

    // full path to file in temp location
    var filePath = Path.GetTempFileName();

    foreach (var formFile in files)
    {
        if (formFile.Length > 0)
        {
            using (var stream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create))
            {
                await formFile.CopyToAsync(stream);
            }
        }
    }

    // process uploaded files
    // Don't rely on or trust the FileName property without validation.

    return Ok(new { count = files.Count, size, filePath});
}
```

Also, you can find the full documentation here. [File uploads in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/tr-tr/aspnet/core/mvc/models/file-uploads?view=aspnetcore-2.2):

Comment: I'm using an adapted version of that code for the back-end which I'm assuming is working as my error turned from an error code 400 to a 500 one. So I'm concluding that my aurelia fetch request is the wrong part. Do you know a way how I can solve this ? using a catch with the fetch is logging an error and no image is being saved.